# How to convert binary data to NSData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, nsdata

I have converted the UIImageview into NSData and stored it as binary data. but i don't know how to retrieve the binary data  to NSData and convert that to UIImageview

my code is below

image save as binary data----

```
-(void) save
{
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back2.png"];
    NSData *dataObj =UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
    NotesDetails *notesDetails = (NotesDetails *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"NotesDetails" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
 notesDetails.imageData=dataObj;
    NSLog(@"NotesDetails: %@",notesDetails);
    NSError *error;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {

    }
}
```

Image Retreive------

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSFetchRequest *fectchreq = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entitydes = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"NotesDetails"
                                                 inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fectchreq setEntity:entitydes];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortdes = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"notesTime" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortdesarray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortdes, nil];
    [fectchreq setSortDescriptors:sortdesarray];
    NSError *error;
    NSMutableArray *storeddata = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fectchreq error:&error] mutableCopy];

    if ([storeddata count] > 0)
    {
        for (NotesDetails *sc in storeddata)
        {
            imgFromDb=[NSData dataWithData:[@"%@",sc.imageData]];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Image : %@",imgFromDb);
    UIImageView *dbImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80,20,90,90)];
    dbImage.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imgFromDb];

    [NoteDetails addSubview:dbImage];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NSKeyedUnarchiver:

```
imgFromDb= [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: sc.imageData];
```

And you can do the opposite (object to data) with NSKeyedArchiver if you prefer it vs UIImagePNGRepresentation().
And there are other ways to do this, for example:

```
imgFromDb= [UIImage imageWithData: sc.imageData];
```